# Temperature sets to cooling when print starts CR10s Pro v1

Tags: creality-cr-10

I've got this second hand printer today, but, when I want to start printing, the temperature sets to cooling mode and the print never starts.

[image: CR 10 S Pro display says: Cool...]

This is what I've done so far...

- Upgraded firmware for the board and screen to Tiny Machines latest version.
- Check temperature manual for bed and nozzle and works fine
- Level the bed
- I used Cura with several profiles, even with an Ender 3 profile from my other machine to see if the slicer is the one giving issues

On other G-codes that i tried, the message changes to in the pause and completing percentage is set to 218 %...

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, to make things weirder, i try printing using pronterface, so i could get the logs, and its working with the same gcode, i used 2 different sd cards, so could it be the sd card reader?

Comment: When i use the sd card, still connected to pronterface, it fails sgain and the only error is a warning about homing division something

Comment: sounds like in flashing your firmware there was some error and you need to re-flash it properly... did you install a bootloader first?

Comment: So you check gcode in notepad++. Try find commands to set cooling in code. Maybe it is start gcode on cura or one of value in settings

Comment: @trish The cr10s pro doesnt need a bootloader, i followed the directions from tinymachines and did it twice

Comment: Like i said earlier the same gcode prints using pronterface, so its not the gcode, the issue is either the sd card or the reader

Comment: @frenciaj the CR10S had versions that came without a bootloader. If you suspect the SD reader of SD card, please test a different SD drive with a known to be working code.

Answer (score 2):

File name is too long, I had the same issue, shortened the file name and now printing perfect

Comment: Do you know what the maximum number of characters allowed is?